# What do I need to know about memory in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, pointers, reference

I've been doing my best to learn C++ but my previous training will fall short in one major issue: memory management.  My primary languages all have automatic garbage collection, so keeping track of everything has never really been necessary.  I've tried reading up on memory management in C++ online, but I have this shaking suspicion that I am strill missing something.

So, here's a multi-part question:

- What is the bare minimum I need to know about memory management? (or, where do I go to find that out)?
- Where do I go for intermediate and advanced knowledge/tutorials/etc (once I am done with the basics)?
  More specifically:
- What is the performance difference between pointers and references?
- I've heard that in loops, you need to make sure that you call `delete` on any new pointers before the loop re-iterates.  Is this correct?  Do you need to do something with references?
- What are some classic examples of memory leaks?
- What do I need to know about the following (and will I ever realistically need to use them -- if so, where?):

  - `malloc`
  - `free`
  - `calloc`
  - `realloc`

*********************** UPDATE *******************

This is to address a reference to lmgtfy in comment one (by Ewan).  If you start reading the information which is available there, it is not useful to the beginner.  It is great theory, I think, but it is neither pertinent or useful to this question.

Comment: Why did someone vote to close? This is a perfectly valid question

Comment: Agreed. It's a perfectly good question.

Comment: I think you should split this question into more bite sized pieces, any answer to all of the questions above will be several pages long.

Comment: @Andreas You're probably right, but it seems that all of these would be related sub-questions.  Do you have suggestions on how it should be broken up?

Comment: @Christopher As someone else stated further down this isn't the type of question that can be answered at SO. I suggest you do as Neil suggested and read a good book on C++ and then get back with specific questions if there's something you don't understand.

Comment: @Andreas fair enough.  Recommendations?

Comment: @Christopher I began with a book called "C++ primer" but that was a long time ago, I think Neils suggestion, "Accelerated C++", is probably a better option today.

Comment: as I mentioned in my post, all of this boils down to discipline.  It's like if you open the refrigerator door to get a soda, you make sure to close the door, you don't just walk away and leave it open.  If you think about it in these terms, it becomes easier to deal with. Knowledge comes with reading, trying to understand the concepts, and then using those concepts by trying to code with them.  The more you continue that cycle, the more experienced you will get.

Comment: I forgot to mention the best book on the subject that changed my life.  It is language agnostic, but the book is timeless.  I'd suggest checking out "Code Complete" by Microsoft Press.  If half of Microsoft's developers read this book, software quality in that company would go up 1000%.

Comment: I know this is marked as C++, but isn't malloc originally a C function? So are you interested in C and C++? I know they are similar but there is a difference

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You really, really need to read a good book - learning C++ frankly is not possible without one. I recommend [Accelerated C++](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/), by Koenig & Moo, two of the originators of C++.

Comment: +1 I think you are 100% correct. There is a lot of reading/practice has to be done.

Comment: +1 Then Proceed directly to Scott Meyers' Effective C++ (and on to More Effective C++, but at least get the first one down)

Comment: +1. The question indicates a lack of knowledge that cannot be patched by a SO answer.

Answer (score 15):

### Memory Management

#### Basics

- Every 'use of' new must be matched by 'use of' delete
- Array new is different form normal new and has its own delete

_

```
 int*  data1 = new int(5);
 delete data1;

 int*  data2 = new int[5];
 delete [] data2;
```

#### Must Know

- Exceptions
- RAII
- Rule of 4.

[throwing exceptions out of a destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor/130123#130123)
[Dynamically allocating an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255612/c-dynamically-allocating-an-array-of-objects/255744#255744)
[Pattern name for create in constructor, delete in destructor (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846144/1846409#1846409)

#### Best Practice

- Never actually use RAW pointers.
- Always wrap pointers in Smart Pointers.
- Learn the different types of smart pointers and when to use each

[Smart Pointers: Or who owns you baby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94227/smart-pointers-or-who-owns-you-baby)

#### Advanced:

- Understanding Exception Guarantees
- Understanding the use of throw clause

[What are the principles guiding your exception handling policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106586/what-are-the-principles-guiding-your-exception-handling-policy/106749#106749)

### Common ways to leak

#### Basics

```
// Every new is matched by a delete.
for(int loop = 0;loop < 10;++loop)
{
    data = new int(5);
}
delete data;
// The problem is that every 'use of' new is not matched by a delete.
// Here we allocate 10 integers but only release the last one.
```

#### Must Know

```
class MyArray
{
    // Use RAII to manage the dynamic array in an exception safe manor.
    public:
        MyArray(int size)
          :data( new int[size])
        {}
        ~MyArray()
        {
            delete [] data;
        }
    // PROBLEM:
    // Ignored the rule of 4.
    // The compiler will generate a copy constructor and assignment operator.
    // These default compiler generated methods just copy the pointer. This will
    // lead to double deletes on the memory.

    private:
        int*   data;
};
```

#### Best Practice

```
// Understand what the properties of the smart pointers are:
//
std::vector<std::auto_ptr<int> >   data;

// Will not work. You can't put auto_ptr into a standard container.
// This is because it uses move semantics not copy semantics.
```

#### Advanced:

```
// Gurantee that exceptions don't screw up your object:
//
class MyArray
{
   // ... As Above: Plus
   void resize(int newSize)
   {
       delete [] data;
       data = new int[newSize];
       // What happens if this new throws (because there is not enough memory)?
       // You have deleted the old data so the old data so it points at invalid memory.
       // The exception will leave the object in a completely invalid state
   }
```

Comment: I know the rule of three, what's my missing fourth?

Comment: Normal Con/Copy Con/Assignment Op/Destructor.

Answer (score 14):

What you need to know about memory management in the simplest sense, is that you need to delete the memory that you allocate on the heap.  So when creating an object like  `MyClass *myClass = new MyClass(x);` you need to have some place in your code that frees/deletes this with a corresponding `delete`.  This appears easy in practice, but without a proper design and the use of helper objects such as shared pointers, this can quickly get messy especially as code is maintained and features added.  For example here is a classic memory leak:

```
try
{
    MyClass *myClass = new MyClass(x);

    // Do some stuff can throw an exception

    delete myClass;
}
catch(...)
{
   // Memory leak on exceptions.  Delete is never called
}
```

OR another big memory management gotcha is calling the wrong type of delete:

```
int* set = new int[100];
delete set;   // Incorrect - Undefined behavior
// delete [] set;  is the proper way to delete an array of pointers
```

A common way to help yourself is to use the RAII idiom.  ([Resource Allocation Is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization))

Here is an example of using the std library in order to prevent a memory leak:

```
try
{ 
    auto_ptr<MyClass> myClass(new MyClass(x));
    // Now the heap allocated memory associated with myClass
    // will automatically be destroyed when it goes out of scope,
    // but you can use it much like a regular pointer

    myClass->memberFunction();
} 
catch (...)
{

}
```

More info on `auto_ptr` can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr).  If you can use C++11,  [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is a highly recommended choice and is often preferred over auto_ptr.

Comment: "delete set;   // Memory Leak!" Undefined behavior!

Comment: "delete set; // Memory Leak!" Will most likely not leak - it's UB which can either do anything you least expect or work just fine or currupt heap and crash the program.

Comment: @sharptooth, all the more reason to avoid it.  Although in my experienc (MS C++ compilers from 6 to 9), it doesn't crash.  Who knows what it does... maybe just delete the first element's worth of memory?

Comment: Bear in mind that `shared_ptr<>` was part of the last technical report, and hence `std::tr1::shared_ptr<>` is perfectly valid.  I don't know how many compilers support it, but even if for some stupid reason you couldn't use Boost it doesn't necessarily matter.

Comment: TR1 != C++ Standard, I'm afraid.

Comment: You may want to mention to beginners that C++ has dynamic memory allocation rather than the heap since the standard doesn't require implementions to have a heap.

Comment: @rmeador Completely agree that it should be avoided. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913343/how-could-pairing-new-with-delete-possibly-lead-to-memory-leak-only for details of how exactly VC++ handles this situation.

Answer (score 5):

First, you should understand the concepts of the [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) and the [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation).

**After** you understand these concepts, proceed to learning the language constructs.

Comment: Actually, you should understand the concepts of automatic variable allocation versus dynamic memory allocation; as well as an object's duration.

Comment: @Thomas, when you talk to your coworkers about code to you refer to them as stack/heap variables or automatic/dynamic variables.  I'd wager a large sum that it's the former.  Don't be so pedantic.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the bare minimum I need to know about memory management? (or,
>   where do I go to find that out)?

For every new, there must be a delete

> Where do I go for intermediate and advanced knowledge/tutorials/etc (once I am done with > the basics)?

Read *Effective C++*, *More Effective C++*, and *Effective STL*. Then google (std::)auto_ptr, (boost::)scoped_ptr, and (boost::)shared_ptr

> More specifically:What is the performance difference between pointers and references?

I do not know off the top of my head, by since a reference is a copy of a pointer value, I don't foresee any large performance issues.

> I've heard that in loops, you need to make sure that you call delete on any new pointers before the loop re-iterates. Is this correct?

Yes.

> Do you need to do something with references?

No.

> What are some classic examples of memory leaks?

```
int * foo() {
...
return new int(...);
}

int main() {
int i = *foo();
...
//the new int() from foo leaks
}
```

> What do I need to know about the following (and will I ever realistically need to use
>   them -- if so, where?):

First of all, you should never `delete` a `malloc`ed pointer and never `free` a pointer created with `new`. In general, these functions should not appear in c++ code. However, if you find yourself in c-land...

malloc : Similar to new (allocates memory on the heap)
free   : Similar to delete (free memory on the heap)
calloc : Similar to new + memset (allocates memory on the heap, sets it to zero)
realloc: Attempts to resize a block of memory, or creates a new block block of memory and copies the old data, `free`ing the old pointer. No real c++ equivalent.

Some neat memory stuff can be found by googleing (is that how it's spelled?) `placement new`

Comment: Good resources for info on `placement new`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362953/what-are-uses-of-the-c-construct-placement-new

Comment: it's worth noting that you should NEVER mix new/free and malloc/delete.  They do not do the same thing, since new/delete will run constructors and destructors, but malloc/free will not.  However, new/delete are often implemented using malloc/free, and that's pretty much the only time you'll see legit usages of those C functions in C++.

Comment: @rmeador. I'll add a bit about that to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should look into [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), they make your life a lot easier when it comes to memory management.

Comment: Better to first learn the basics than to hide behind an abstraction and run scared when it breaks.

Comment: So better not learn a language with GC first? its fine to learn abstractions before details, but good to know that there are details to learn

Comment: That article started well but that example (in the article) is horrible.

Answer (score 3):

Book called "Memory as a Programming Concept in C and C++" is a very good read for someone who is new to C/C++.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Memory-Programming-Concept-Frantisek-Franek/dp/0521520436/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1260891909&sr=8-1

Answer (score 2):

From your list, you've missed `new` and `delete` - some say never to use `malloc` and `free`.

Also the oft forgotten `delete[]`.

Comment: The list is of things he quite correctly suspects he might not need to know about.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, this is a lot to tackle.

The most important thing is to be consistently diligent and disciplined.  This is true with any resource in any language, even safer managed language.  People feel that when a language manages their memory for them, they don't have to think about it.  But it's always best to release any resources as quickly as possible after your finished with them.  I've always felt "Garbage Collection" has made programmers lazy in recent years.

When ever I allocate memory in a language like c++, I make sure that I deallocate it first, before using it.  In other words, I write the allocate, and deallocate and afterwards fill in the middle.  It is important to get into a consistent habit.  I think that's the bare minimum to learn... proper and disciplined management of resources.  That's not just about memory, it should be applied to all resources, including database references, file references, context handles, and other such animals.

The entire subject of memory management in C++ is fairly vast.  I would say read, study, and code as much as possible.

example:

```
char* myusedmemory;

myusedmemory = (char *)malloc(1000);  // allocate memory

free(myusedmemory);  //  immediately deallocate memory

/*  go back and fill in the code between */
```

There are plenty of good references to go for additional knowledge on the subject.  I found going through the tutorials on relisoft.com was helpful for me, though the main tutorial on there is Windows specific.  [Another good reference can be found here.](http://www.mycplus.com/tutorials/cplusplus-programming-tutorials/memory-management/3/)

As far as differences between pointers and references, one of the main differences is flexibility.  You have to define the reference immediately ( int iExample;  int& refExample = iExample; )  I wouldn't think there would be much of a performance difference.  However, pointers being more powerful and more flexible will be more dangerous, and will require the aforementioned discipline to manage.

[examples of memory leaks are here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++MemoryCorruptionAndMemoryLeaks.html).  but you can find more by googling "memory leaks in C++"

As far as the [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/), [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/free/), [calloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/), [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/), these are just functions like any other commands, in these particular cases, functions included in the stdlib.  You should just have an understanding of what they do and how to use them, just like you would with any other functions, just like the common printf().

as a note:  [Smart pointers](http://www.relisoft.com/resource/smartptr.html) are a very good way to go and are generally safer.

as another note, I wanted to mention, [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556154844), the best book I've read on the subject of resource management.  I've read it cover to cover many, many times.

Answer (score 2):

In other languages you already have to keep track of database connections, window handles, sockets, etc. with mechanisms such as "finally" (in Java) or "using" (in C#). In C++, just add memory to that list. It's not really conceptually any different.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that often catches students:  Large, really large objects such as arrays, should be allocated in dynamic memory (i.e. using `new`).

Also, don't pass around large objects.  Pass pointers, preferable smart pointers, to the objects.  Copying large objects consumes a lot of processor time.

Set up and document rules about object allocation and ownership.  Does the callee or the caller own the object?

Don't return references to local objects, nor pointers to local objects.

Answer (score 1):

Learn about RAII. Some people here pointed it out, but at the same time explained the new/delete stuff, without stressing importance of RAII. With RAII you don't have to worry about memory management.

People new to C++, tend to code like in Java puting "new" everywhere. This is in many cases a bad habit, in some cases you can't avoid it(but from the experience on my projects, this is most likely never).

Just adding this comment to stress it ;) However all the comments are perfectly right.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is mentioning new and delete, but most of the time, you don't need and shouldn't use them explicitely:

- The best thing is to use standard containers and let the do the memory management.
- When that is not possible, use smart pointers with either reference counting or, in last resort, smarter garbage collection.

Of course for performance reasons you might want to have an occasional new and delete pair in a performance critical, but that should be the exception rather than the rule.

Answer (score 0):

`new` and `delete` are the two most important keywords for memory management.  And at its simplest you just need to remember to call `delete` for every object that you call `new` on.  Therefore if you call `new` in a loop, you'll need to make sure that you call `delete` on each of those `new`'ed objects.  You don't need to do it from within the loop so long as you save a copy of each pointer somewhere that can be deleted later.

`malloc`, `free`, `calloc`, and `realloc` are all probably more advanced than what you need to worry about.  I guess just remember they are there if the standard `new`/`delete` ever feels limiting.

That all said, smart pointers can be a big help, but sometimes its helpful to know how to do stuff the hard way before tackling smart pointers.

Comment: "`malloc` et al are advanced": surely you're joking.

Comment: No, for C++ they only matter when you're writing a replacement `operator new`. That is definitely advanced.

Comment: @MSalters: Agreed.  The original post was asking about c++.  For c++ I consider `new`/`delete` to be the de facto method of memory allocation.  The only reason to use 'malloc', etc would be when you are trying to do something beyond the capabilities of `new`/`delete`

Comment: They don't matter at all. Even a replacement operator new can call global ::operator new(size_t) to request blocks of memory. You never have to touch malloc().

Comment: They do matter if you're looking at very old C code for some reason. There's still a lot out there.

Answer (score 0):

As I've been learning C++, I've found that using a memory analysis tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is indispensable in helping to find memory leaks.  When you run your program (compiled with debug symbols) from Valgrind, it will identify the lines where memory gets allocated but is never deallocated later.

I use these command line arguments:

```
 valgrind --leak-check=yes --num-callers=8 ./myExecutable
```

Note that your program will run much slower than when run on its own, but it's often worth the effort.