# why would the optimization ignore the if statement when function has warning [-Wreturn-type]?

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization, compiler-optimization, undefined-behavior

OS: ubuntu2204

compiler: gcc 11.2 x86_64

here's a simple code:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

int func(int val) {
    if (val == 1) {
    } else {
        abort();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    func(argc);
}
```

when I compile it without any optimization, and run it, it works fine.

but when I compile it with `g++ tmp.cpp -O3`, it turns out that `func` would ignore the input value, and just call `abort`.

of course I can fix it by adding a return statement at the end of `func`,
but still, why?

here's some output from `objdump -d a.out` of optimized function `func`:

```
0000000000001060 <_Z4funci>:
    1060:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1064:   50                      push   %rax
    1065:   58                      pop    %rax
    1066:   50                      push   %rax
    1067:   e8 e4 ff ff ff          call   1050 <abort@plt>
```

Comment: "it works fine" should be "it has undefined behavior".  Any observed behavior is allowed, because it has **undefined behavior**.  Could crash.  Could "work fine".  Could email your browser history to your grandmother, and then format your hard drive.

Comment: A function that simply falls off the end (which happens in your code if `val == 1`) has undefined behaviour.   When compiling with significant optimisation (e.g. `-O3`) some compilers that detect undefined behaviour impose an assumption that the undefined behaviour cannot occur.  In your code, that can mean assuming (and never testing) that `val` is never equal to `1`, so always calling `abort()`.    That reasoning process is not necessarily applied when compiling without optimisation.

Comment: @Peter -- a bit of a technicality, but it's the **program** that has undefined behavior, not the function itself.

Comment: Compile with gcc or clang `-fsanitize=undefined` and they'll tell you about UB instead of having surprising things happen after the abstract machine encounters UB, like "jumping" to part of your code you weren't expecting.  (And rarely even before; see [Does undefined behaviour retroactively mean that earlier visible side-effects aren't guaranteed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77146088)).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, flowing off the end of a non-void function without a `return` statement is undefined behavior in C++. See [Why does flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning a value not produce a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1610030/5740428) In general, compilers use undefined behavior for optimization. See also:

- [Benefit of endless-loops without side effects in C++ being undefined behavior compared to C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76960441/5740428)
- [Is undefined behavior worth it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2771825/5740428)
- [Does undefined behavior really help modern compilers to optimize generated code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49001802/5740428)

Intuitively, the compiler can see that there is undefined behavior in the `if (val == 1)` branch because you flow off the end of the function. The compiler can then say that this branch is unreachable and always call `abort()`, as if the condition was always `false`.

More concretely, LLVM starts out with the following IR:

```
entry:
  // ...
  br i1 %cmp, label %if.then, label %if.else

if.then:
  br label %if.end
if.else:
  call void @abort()
  unreachable
if.end:
  unreachable
```

Depending on the value of `val`, control flow branches either into `if.then` (which immediately goes to `if.end`), or to `if.else` (which calls a `[[noreturn]]` function).

In a `SimplifyCFG` (Simplify Control Flow Graph) pass, this structure is simplified to:

```
  %1 = xor i1 %cmp, true
  call void @llvm.assume(i1 %1)
  call void @abort()
  unreachable
```

The compiler now assumes that `val ^ 1` is always true, which means it `val` must be `false`. There is no more branch, but rather, control flows directly into `abort()`.
Intuitively, if statements are altered to prevent reaching an `unreachable` instruction.
Concretely, a `br` which jumps to a basic block containing `unreachable` is eliminated.

After further optimization passes, the whole function essentially becomes:

```
  tail call void @abort()
  unreachable
```

*See the whole optimization pipeline at https://godbolt.org/z/bnvh7KrG4*

On a debug build, with no optimizations, the compiler doesn't simplify the if statement. The code works "as intended". Both GCC and clang output something like:

```
        je      .L2
        call    abort
.L2:
        ud2
```

Flowing off the end of the function becomes a `ud2` pseudo-instruction (generated from `unreachable`), and executing it would immediately halt the program.

This answer is specific to clang and you're using GCC, however, the optimizations that these compilers perform are relatively similar, especially in trivial cases like these.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256324/discussion-on-answer-by-jan-schultke-why-would-the-optimization-ignore-the-if-st); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6):

It not about the warning warning, it's due to what the warning means. Every branch of execution must have a valid end (for non-`void` function, that would usually be a `return` with value, throwing exception or terminating program), otherwise your program has Undefined Behaviour. And [Undefined Behaviour can result in time travel (among other things)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Most likely, optimiser notices that there is no way `val` can be equal to `1` without invoking Undefined Behaviour, and since it's allowed to assume there is no UB in the code, it can assume that `val == 1` is never true, so it optimises everything down to only reasonable path in code.

Comment: To be fair, that UB-based optimization would still be surprising

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's becoming quite common, and is something to watch out for. See also [Old New Thing - Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm well aware, but what I'm saying that of all things you could choose as a compiler to do here, this is amongst the most surprising things to do. Like, if you feel you're doing whatever you like, because, well, UB, then just *don't* call `abort` at all but `ret` right away. There you go, maximally optimized function.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The compiler is just making the smallest assumption to avoid UB _"that the caller would never pass `1`"_ . Doing `ret` _"...right away..."_ would still be UB as the function does not return a value.  Note that `abort` is `[[noreturn]]` so the `abort` path is not UB .

Comment: @Jarod42 I reworded it, do you think it's better now?

Comment: @RichardCritten no, what the compiler here does is make a very complex reasoning here: it looks at all the (in this case, 2) paths, and *only picks the one that has side effects*. (you can check that by substituting `abort` with, say `sinf` and `printf`) That's what surprising here – unlike what Yksisarvinen says, this is not because that's the path with no UB; it's the only path that is *observable*. And that is surprising.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Indeed, it doesn't optimise it that much if the other branch has a printf. And yet it goes SIGSEGV regardless of number of arguments: https://godbolt.org/z/311fP1TfY

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I'll be honest, that should probably be something the compiler should do more than *warn* about.

Comment: @MarcusMüller "that should probably be something the compiler should do more than warn about" - That's a *quality of implementation* issue. The compiler is not required to issue a diagnostic, but sure, good compilers can. Issuing more than a diagnostic gets problematic since the code is syntactically valid, so the compiler is obligated to generate *something* (even if not sensible).

Comment: @MarcusMüller: “no, what the compiler here does is make a very complex reasoning here: it looks at all the (in this case, 2) paths, and only picks the one that has side effects”: No, that is what you have intuited or assumed the compiler would reason, based on your personal experience with thinking and how brains reason. It is not how compilers are designed. The actual design of an optimizer is more like that, as the `val == 1` branch is analyzed, it is determined to impose no requirements on the program…

Comment: … This branch is then pruned from the tree the optimizer is building to represent the program, leaving only the `else` branch. Or, another way of viewing it is that the `if … else` is analyzed as “(if val == 1, anything) or (if val != 1, abort)”, and a valid rule for optimizing that “or” statement is transform it to “abort()”. It is a dispassionate reduction according to preset rules about logical transformations, not a conscious reasoning about what to do.

Comment: yep, you're right, it became obvious to me after reading Jan's answer: side-effect free functions: who cares about them if you're not using their return value. @EricPostpischil

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Indeed, the Standard waived jurisdiction over *many* things as a "quality of implementation" issues.  In situations where some kinds of pre-Standard implementations would reliably process a construct in useful fashion, but others wouldn't, waiving jurisdiction was intended to support whatever combination of features and guarantees would best serve their customers, on a "quality of implementation" basis.  The notion that compilers would go out of their way to make inferences based upon the notion that programmers wouldn't expect that compilers to be compatible with predecessors...

Comment: ...would have been seen as absurd, but many people have been gaslighted into accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

Compile with `-O2 -fsanitize=undefined` for testing so your programs will reliably and noisily fault (with a message about what happened) when Undefined Behaviour is encountered.  UB means a program *might* crash, but it might do literally anything else first or instead, like jump wildly to some other block of code, perhaps with register values inappropriate for that block.

---

Falling off the end of a non-`void` function (without a `return`) is undefined behaviour in C++.
Unlike in C where it's only UB for the caller to actually use the return value.  Early C didn't have `void` so functions that didn't want to return were just declared like `foo();` with the return type defaulting to `int`, but the function wouldn't use a `return` statement.  So fun fact, that function compiled as C does need a branch and a `ret` instruction: [compiling with `-xc` on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:11,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:11,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:11,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:11,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmath.h%3E%0A%0Adouble+globalvar%3B%0Aint+func(int+val)+%7B%0A++++if+(val+%3D%3D+1)+%7B%0A++++++++//globalvar+%3D+sqrt(val)%3B%0A++++%7D+else+%7B%0A++++++++abort()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main(int+argc,+char*+argv%5B%5D)+%7B%0A++++func(argc)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:38.996973627323825,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2+-Wall+-xc%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:100,l:%274%27,m:72.12213445811932,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:27.877865541880688,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:61.00302637267618,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

---

**Compilers can assume UB doesn't happen.**
The behaviour of programs that encounter UB is unconstrained, so calling `abort` is allowed.
This lets the compiler avoid even checking the condition, because branchy asm isn't a visible side-effect that other threads (or external observers like debuggers) are guaranteed to be able to see, per the as-if rule.

In this case, GCC and Clang treat the `}` at the bottom of a non-`void` function as `__builtin_unreachable();`.  They don't care what happens for program executions that do encounter UB, that's the whole point as far as the optimizer is concerned.  (See [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html))

The compiler has to make asm that implements the *visible* parts of the function's behaviour (after inlining any callees if it wants) for all inputs / paths of execution that don't encounter undefined behaviour.

A visible side-effect like a `volatile int sink = val;` in the non-abort side of the `if()` would be another matter. The C++ standard *does* still allow optimizers to remove that, but GCC and Clang don't in practice in this case.  (Even assignment to a non-`volatile` global still happens with `gcc -O3`, but it still lets that path of execution fall into the other to call `abort`.)    ([**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyahUAUgBMAIUtXyKxqiIEh1ZpgDC6egFc2TEABmcncAGQImbAA5PwAjbFIQCy1yAAd0JWIXJi9ffyC0jKyhcMiYtnjE5PtsR2chESIWUiJcvwDgh2wnbMbmolLouISklKUmlrb8zomBiKGKkeSASnt0H1JUTi5LQIjUXxwAajNAj3HMegJYgDokU9wzLQBBXf3D7BOzthYiJDuHk9Xi9MOtYowjsB6OhYhJQT5wdhTjYXgB6VEAN28vwYnyO%2BPRRwA7sQkEcsUZnIxyEcDsZgJD0NglEd4gBPISYI5/T6kbAARx8BD5XPiSBYGJcGyOxi5oOZR3GZE%2B8UEfKOSGIzhMRwUVhu%2BIA4h4PIqSHyWXRSOMjtgMcxiaSjkwhABaCk4xhAiJESHQ2FXYTIoHe4RHGg%2BJioCA%2B8kSZYnADsKOe%2BPxBBoRwgGIkXwAIqc80ceAmzMmgWnK0d0VCYXCwRDC4r%2BS1s/HkQTUTKnD4JPQ2UcIoGFSQZbShONjEQK1X8bWA7Gmzn6MGXpWy0XaiokynZ/iWLEyEQIMtV6m0xuQ4mC2iAFSh30/CIxsPNYCoGmocWkW8y0jADEzAAVhsIC81Lcs1zTCMowgN9UFPQIU0vF5b1RLhVnobggP4AIuB0ch0G4DxbFsRV1k2T5dj4cgiG0DDVgAayCAAOG4AE52IANnYxNAi4iw%2BIsQIWIsIDDG4aR%2BDYEAgJSPCCKIrh%2BCUEAUjo/CMPIOBYBQDA2FSXEKCoCB9MMxhEjpEweETLQeAEBgiASVSIFiejyFiCJmjZbgaM81hSDZAB5WJdG6DSaP0jhhCCph%2B3cnBYh8YAPD7VTeH4HAfhMSRNPIQg%2BR6e10oI7B1G6HwnN8/gfVqdyrliUhvK8HB3KIUgCBkjLVhoIxgCUAA1AhsCJILUmYaq5GEMQJE4GQpsUFQNHc/RgiMEw0FI6xDGuVTIFWdBUnqJh0tdILAiOV0AHU%2B0umglGMLIAC8kUCPNIxwOhIkwfh0HtUgOpwPaTxqOpsjcJhPG8doDDCeZykqAx0kyY6pgCezkeKJhBgRkZ7K6HoGlmNGDAJ46%2BhaHHhkSfHieh/Jaf6KnFhp1YlAorYpEw7DcPcpSjnUFiuNdLjpFpdaGRsm4tBuHgs3wYgyBOYSS34DSdGWVYkGwFgcESEGsK4KTyBkuTyAU37uBUtTaPozXyGYkSOO43j%2BMEwJhNE8TDcCXm8qUtW7e0xAdIQeAID09ADKMyhqDMoyQGAHgPYc%2BgnOtag3Ly/zvMmnPApCsKnEmqLmCIWL4ryxLktS%2Bh6HSmisvpXKCIK8KCGK9yyoqqqMsoYQ6ryhqmsClrtgI9rOuqnq%2BsG4bRvGvCaMEabxEkeaV8WtRNDy/R7IlzbrFsHbYmBg6juyU7zsum669%2B/7AeZeA2dqdvXAgdwSfsuGymppGilRvTdGhQUbZGZojfGr9CZMApq0IBpMoHk1mOAvG9g6Z5GAZOSm8M/4ljWBsTmeDDY4XNnzbgAshYizFu%2BVAxZAg3AsPLQg5plaBFVrbTS9tmJm0NsbGSosbiJmkCxLQLFuIiSEQJCwpD/ZW3sDbdWWlQ4RzQFHcyCRY6mTUQnKySdbL2ToGnZymd3L5x8n3MxhdwolyjtFcucVzGt2wElFKaVJpNxyuPTKwp26dzyt3VAlVtg0VqobAiw9mpYC8bRDqXU%2BAzxYP1IaI0xoTT7pvGa69ZCb2UNvFaSRDD0kPjYbaDUz6EQvhObgZ0LrXT7PfBIj9ylk3Bh/SGX8QiQxQTTEBWMOmY2Ot0hBYMib9A6S00Z2Df4s1JugmGjMpkLAgWzDmc1uZcBIRbQi5DBbC1FuLekxZEzS1lkwxWpBWHsMUfbbWusRgg24SkXhftFJyNUupO26yLDSRAAIoRIixFcQkdIKRMjXnKQ4RrYO4cUDrCIKkSqmj44WSiOwbYuyqGQlQLQ5ODD%2BDYGYWQAgmADAZLXnNbJ8hcnLV3gYIkTVUjTwkhsl5lsuBBUqgi306BMwYv2TQuhDCsxeGjhZS5yxA6cK1jrPW1B1l8KCEBBhQEeDsR4FofiPAxKBETOxMFbLrYfKlQ7X5PBpYaq0BYIFiYrWJi4jwFizLfb6u2RC65XzWWuslRrVY/1MiuGkEAA)). So it does look like GCC is generating code right up until UB is reached, only then giving up and letting that path of execution fall off into whatever it decided to put next in the binary, either another block of this function, or the next.  (GCC/Clang pad between functions with NOPs, vs. MSVC padding with 0xCC `int3` trap instructions on x86.)

---

**This isn't a case of "time travel" or truly retroactive effects on earlier code.**  The actual behaviour is explainable as weirdness (a wild jump) happening after the UB-causing operation is reached, although that's not something you should rely on.

- Calls with `val != 1` call `abort`, as expected.  Well-defined behaviour.
- Calls with `val == 1` encounter UB in the abstract machine.  Instead of making demons fly out of your nose, the actual behaviour is to call `abort`.  Literally anything is allowed by the C++ standard, which is intentionally written to allow the optimizer to assume that UB never happens and not waste instructions in cases like this.

  In practice, the compiler made this asm by removing paths of execution that *unavoidably* lead to UB.  (Non-inline function calls might exit the program instead of returning, so compilers typically can't remove them.)

You can explain it in terms of possible real-world UB effects including randomly jumping to any code that's in your program. Often in the same function, but falling off the bottom of a function without a `return` can sometimes result in compilers just stopping asm code-gen and literally letting execution fall off the bottom, into the top of the next function.  Sometimes compilers emit a `ud2` (illegal instruction trap), sometimes they let execution fall off the end of a block or function.  See *[Why is no value returned if a function does not explicity use 'ret'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578122/why-is-no-value-returned-if-a-function-does-not-explicity-use-ret)* for an example of a hand-written asm `main` with/without a `ret`, leading to fall-through into `__libc_csu_init` (from CRT startup code).  See also *[What if there is no return statement in a CALLed block of code in assembly programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205054/what-if-there-is-no-return-statement-in-a-called-block-of-code-in-assembly-progr)* re: the asm consequences in general.

---

#### Retroactive effects of UB on earlier side-effects

Where things get interesting is when there is a visible side-effect in the abstract machine before (in source order) it encounters UB.

```
#include <cstdlib>

//volatile
int globalint;

int func(int val) {
    if (val == 1) {
        globalint = val;
    } else {
        abort();
    }

    //__builtin_unreachable();     // same asm with these or with falling off the end
    //return 0;                    // (in C++ not C)
}
```

Even without `volatile`, GCC13 -O2 compiles it like this ([**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyahUAUgBMAIUtXyKxqiIEh1ZpgDC6egFc2TEABWcncAGQImbAA5PwAjbFIpYIAHdCViFyYvX38g8lT05yFwyJi2eMSeYIdsJ0yRIhZSImy/AOrsRyKmBqaiEui4hKT7RubW3Oqx/ojB8uGqgEp7dB9SVE4uSwBmCNRfHABqM22PJSJMegJYgDokE9xDp4B6Z8OMNmSGbEOAd2IkIcALTqVBPEiHIikbAsIiQpAEJSHFhIliHDyHZKkdDAUjsciHJjoOEeWxkrQAQVeOz2Bx%2BJw8bFhSDuDzMlNemFWsUYh2A9HQsQkXJ8POwJxslPZVOeADdvLDvk8Xm9/kRAfKjM5GAT9sZgHz0NgkfEAJ5CTDwn7QgCOPgI0Mt8SQLFlLjWyKYlq5xsO5zIP3igmhhwRRGcJkOCisNyeAHEPBj/dCkXRSOdDthZcw/gDCUIgZrFYxpRE4fzBRIyxLpaXhIcaD4mKgIGXDrKJItjgB2SUU5WHAg0Q4QDv0Y7bAAiJ0nhx4XbMvelA4HrwrQvoIrFE9nShtzVHnYlKuRTh8EnopsHTCukSRELRGCY52MRGXK6e66r9Zn7YkNcpAdF1nToVB7PsPyeFhYjIIgIEWAD%2B2VYD3yeVDDleAB9TDYntegI0wptoRYVAXTFeDENXZ5oSINYmEOLREJQjkACo6zhJkIlbesmmAVBdRdUgWORUhgFlMxAhsQJJwXJdAOVRtmwgXjUAQ7Y%2B2YikWOeLhlnobhAn4AIuB0ch0G4UlrFsP1VnWekLG2PhyCIbRdOWABrEBtgADhuABOPyADY/O7bZAosUKHO8ixgn0rhpH4Nggi0chjNM8yuH4JQQBSlyTN08g4FgFAPi%2BRgKCoCBSu%2BRI9RMHhuy0HgBAYIgEmyiBYlc8hYgiJpTW4JzetYUhTQAeViXRajypyPg4YQxpvAb8vIHBcOADwL2y3h%2BBwJkTEkFbCGhOps220zsHUWofDawb%2BDLTpuquWI8VGrwcG6qECCSnblhoIxgCUAA1AhsF%2BMbkmYO65GEMQJE4GQYcUFQNG6/RtkMfU0DJaxDGubLIGWdBkm6bagTG7ZgQAdQvYEaCUYwMgAL3FKcmxwOhIkwfh0GzUhSAIHACfg%2BxOmmzI3C9CYAmasJZjKCoDAKDIhGlpW0hVpgBgVhZRa6eppjV5qajqIRemabWhkqUY%2BiNm2Lflq2pGWJRbI2Z3DAMozuoyw51G8wKgUC6R3iMSMGpuLQbh4Ed8GIMhjgc%2Bd%2BDynRFmWJAYRwRIRbihLyCSwIUrSnnuCynLnNc9PyE8nz/KCkKwoi7Yopiz2uG2b2VoylOq8KxAioQeAIBK9BPhqyhqGq8qQGAHgW5a/D2uoLqVuG/rofX0aJqmpxobm5giEWy9urWnwNq26G9v1Q7TOO8Wzu6y7rtunbKGER6Vue17TXezZTK%2Bj9Pgf0AbA1BuDSGxknKCFhuISQiMYHIzUJoFa%2Bhmph1MDjOwz1hZExJpkMmFNqYXh5nzAWQt4AuzFqbAIEB3B2zlqUJ2zVlbdDtqwzIlt5jWxNt0c2LRvBtAMLwg2fQuGK2NobQRuRJFiMdtwj2rs1ju3nO3QyqUfbcD9gHIOIc%2BJgnnjcCwsdCAkFIInRyixe75Wrp5Iu7d85JWDjcbs0hvJaG8kFHyrjwoWA0d3Mu9gK6pwKoPEeaAx5lQSJPKqkSapoAwQ1Jqi82rphXt1Ley0hp9W3pNaa%2B8x7zSPktU%2B2B1qbXoPQbaTlr4HX/rtB0D9jRPyuqgG6mwnIPTiqZb%2B/U/6fQFkAgq/0WCAxBmDCGUM36ILhvA2QiDlDILRiAPxGDsZWVxjgyhZl8FCEIZTIENNKmkISOQ5phM9bi1cHQqW0iZYhC9OI3WHDVZ3PVoUTh8iJGXJofwu2IizbTCeTwqROR7kvgdkwhRqilF2Q9nFdRJczJaP9oHYOod9Rzm7JHaOJj47mJ2MnSuNiM5Z2GCLOxKU85d3SoE7KuUq56W4BYRKIBnGuPcZ4wK3jpC%2BP8bSzKxK0792HigVYRBkg3RidPBIUR2CbFRbovkqADHbCMfwbApiyCCwMDMuBCN5nyEWajVBBhfh4mSHdJlXBEWaK4GNG6kq4ToGHIq9F%2Bi5xquMRALw49yoWKJSE6umcWDZ2oNaxxXlAhGMCDwPyPAtBhR4DFbY3Y/L8tLoK%2BlQq3I1zZTwSOiatAWG5d2Et3ZAo8G8u3TuGbkWCqDdalldae45urnzdIrhpBAA%3D%3D)):

```
# GCC -O3
func(int):
        dec     edi               # peephole optimization for  cmp edi, 1
        jne     .L2
        mov     DWORD PTR globalint[rip], 1
## fall-through from the if body to the else!
.L2:
        push    rax               # align the stack before a call
        call    abort             # it doesn't tailcall with jmp because noreturn functions like abort often want to backtrace
```

But clang optimizes away the non-`volatile` side-effect on `globalint`, applying the unreachability backward to the whole basic block.

```
# clang17 -O3
func_nonvolatile(int):
        push    rax
        call    abort@PLT
```

With `volatile globalint`, that's a *visible* side-effect in terms of the C++ standard, same as a printf or other I/O.  The C++ standard allows UB to retroactively "break" earlier code including visible side-effects (the behaviour of the entire program from start to finish is undefined, for executions that encounter UB at any point).  But real compilers aren't that aggressive.

```
# clang -O3
func_volatile(int):                               # @func(int)
        cmp     edi, 1
        je      .LBB0_1
        push    rax
        call    abort@PLT
     # abort is a noreturn function; there's no actual fall-through here.
.LBB0_1:
        mov     dword ptr [rip + globalint], 1
 ## fall off the end of the asm, into whatever function's next in the binary
```

See also:

- [Does undefined behaviour retroactively mean that earlier visible side-effects aren't guaranteed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77146088/does-undefined-behaviour-retroactively-mean-that-earlier-visible-side-effects-ar) which contrasts the C vs. C++ wording.  ISO C++ is explicit about nothing being guaranteed in a program which will later encounter UB, ISO C isn't but apparently the standard reading of the C standard matches C++.
- https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3128.pdf is a proposal for "concrete" UB in C, not allowing retroactive breakage.  Note that this example is *not* retroactive; no *observable* behaviour or even any modification of variables happened before UB was reached for the cases that do encounter UB.

That n3128 paper does cite some rare examples of actual retroactive effects on visible side effects (volatile load or store) sequenced before UB.  I/O functions normally can't get re-ordered because compilers don't know if they'll ever return; they could block or exit the program, since optimizers typically treat them like mostly a black box.  They do have to know enough about them to warning about printf args matching format strings.

Anyway, as I showed with the `volatile` example, clang chooses not to "break" it (or misses the optimization?) even though it knows for sure the abstract machine will encounter UB along that path of execution.  So the "concrete UB" proposal probably wouldn't be too hard for compilers to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not returning a value on all paths; it thus has [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and is simply broken. The compiler has *no* obligation to generate anything specific when the code has UB - *anything* is valid. You simply cannot make any assumptions when your code is fundamentally flawed (and no; the compiler is not required to even issue a warning, *you* have to know the rules and not break them).

Comment: You can (and should) compile with GCC or Clang `-O2 -fsanitize=undefined` to define the behaviour of most things that are normally UB.  Then they're guaranteed to noisily abort with a message about what happened.

Comment: True that the compiler isn't *required* to issue warning, but good warnings (and tools like `-fsanitize=undefined` ubsan) make it slightly less of a minefield of usability disaster to have compilers optimize aggressively based on the assumption of no UB.