# warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int [3][4]' to parameter of type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am trying to learn on 2D array in C and trying to implement the snipet code number 25 in page 59 of the book "Understanding pointers in C - Yashavant Kanetkar".

When compiling the code copied from the book I get the following warning:

```
upic_25.c:26:11: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int [3][4]' to parameter of type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  display(a,3,4);
          ^
upic_25.c:8:19: note: passing argument to parameter 'q' here
void display(int *q, int row, int col){
                  ^
1 warning generated.
```

Here is the snippet:

```
// understanding pointers in C - Yashavant Kanetkar
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void display(int *q, int row, int col);


void display(int *q, int row, int col){
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i<row; i++){
    for(j = 0; j< col; j++){
      printf("%d", *(q+i *col + j));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}


int main(){
  int a[][4] = {
    5,7,5,9,
    4,6,3,1,
    2,9,0,6
  };

  display(a,3,4);
  int *p;
  int (*q)[4];

  p = (int *) a;
  q = a;

  printf("%p %p", p, q);
  p++;
  q++;
  printf("\n");
  printf("%p %p", p, q);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your problem is that Yashavant Kanetkar's books are garbage.  There's a typographical error in the title.  It should be *Misleading Information About Pointers in C*.  Yashavant Kanetkar does not teach you the actual C language.  He teaches a strange non-language which he has deduced after long experimentation with an ancient copy of Turbo C.

Comment: No offense, but that book is a singularly bad source of learning C. It took me years to un-learn all the wrong concepts.

Comment: The simplest fix is to change the call `display(a,3,4);` to `display(&a[0][0],3,4);`.  Also, for your sanity, I would change the `"%d"` in the first `printf` call to `"%d "`.  Spaces are cheap; there's no need to jam the output digits together as they were originally.

Comment: Seriously, your best bet may very well be to throw that book away.  Yashavant Kanetkar's books are popular, and I suppose they do a good job of teaching the basics of C to beginners, at the unfortunate cost of a certain amount of misinformation mixed in.  But I can't imagine how many misleading or outright wrong explanations there must be in a book of his dedicated solely to an important but difficult concept like pointers.  (In particular: find the sentence where it says "An array name is a constant pointer" — I'm sure it's there somewhere — and blacken it out with a Sharpie® marker.)

Comment: But it's good — very good — that your compiler gave you a warning, and that you paid attention to it, and that you asked about it here.  You did nothing wrong: the fault is all the author's.

Comment: Also the author of *Let Us C* which contains this howler shown in a previous SO question [Why does this code print 1 2 2 and not the expected 3 3 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63505019/why-does-this-code-print-1-2-2-and-not-the-expected-3-3-1)

Comment: @WeatherVane Also some commentary at [this now-deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58114529).  As I commented then: "It's bad enough to make ill-informed guesses, but then to present them as established fact takes a level of deranged chutzpah that always just floors me when I encounter it."

Comment: @SteveSummit the source of half the SO questions?

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, maybe not, but certainly the source of `i++ + i++` of them. :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit. Many thanks for your comments. I have to say that maybe this book is of bad quality but what I found appealing with it was that it adress one of the most difficult difficult subjects of C for beginners (namely pointers) with many different exercices giving the opportunity to be exposed to that subject from many different angles. I found that other books skim the subject theoretically without giving opportunity to exercice. Could you recommend an alternative good book specifically on pointers with similar amount and variety of exercices on pointers?

Comment: @SteveSummit, using `display(&a[0][0],3,4);` will result in UB when accessing `q[4]`. The only thing that may work is `display((int*)&a,3,4);` though the standard is bit vague about it. The proper solution should use VLA types.

Comment: @ecjb Unfortunately I don't have anything specifically on pointers to recommend.  *C: A Modern Approach* by K.N. King was once much recommended.  I can recommend my own on-line C Programming Notes (beginning and intermediate) at https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/cclass.html .

Comment: Thanks a lot @SteveSummit. I will look carefully at your notes and look to the book of K.N. King

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is a strongly-typed language.  This means that every object and every expression has a type, and the actual meaning of an expression very much depends on its type.  For example, the expressions `a = 7; b = 3; c = a / b` have fundamentally different behavior depending on which of `a`, `b`, and `c` are integer or floating-point types.

Pointers, too, have types.  A pointer is not "just an address". Any pointer has type "pointer to `<othertype>`", where `<othertype>` is obviously some other type.

A pointer *must* have a type, otherwise pointer arithmetic could not work.  In the expression `p + i`, where `p` is a pointer and `i` is an integer, the actual address computed is the address value in `p`, plus `i * sizeof(*p)`.  You have to know the type of the pointed-to object so you know what size to scale the offset by.  Also, just as in a previous example, if `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` are pointers, the expression `*p1 = *p2 / *p3*` will have fundamentally different behavior depending on which of `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` point to integer or floating-point types.

So with that background out of the way, now we can analyze the code in the question.  Given the declaration

```
int a[][4]
```

the variable `a` has type "array of some number of arrays of 4 `int`".

But now let's create some pointers.  The expression

```
&a
```

would generate a pointer to the entire array, and this pointer would have type "pointer to array of some number of arrays of 4 `int`".

We can also create pointers to individual elements and subelements of `a`.  The expression

```
&a[0]
```

generates a pointer to `a`'s first element.  Now, `a` is an array of arrays, so its first element `a[0]` is an array, namely its first row.  So `&a[0]` has type "pointer to array of 4 `int`".

Consider the expression

```
&a[0][0]
```

Now, `&a[0]` is `a`'s first row, so `&a[0][0]` is the first element of the first row.  It's an actual `int`.  So `&a[0]]0]` has type "pointer to `int`".

Finally, what if we just mention `a` by itself in an expression, as in the function call

```
display(a, 3, 4);
```

Whenever you mention an array in an expression like that, the value you get is not "the whole array".  Instead, due to a principle sometimes known as the [correspondence between arrays and pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868367), what you get is a pointer to the array's first element, or `&a[0]`.  We already figured that one out, just above. So when we call `display(a, 3, 4)`, what gets passed as `display`'s first argument is a value of type "pointer to array of 4 `int`".

But the definition of function `display` does not say that. The definition of function `display` says that its first argument is supposed to be of type `int *`, or "pointer to `int`". So this is why the compiler complained, and the warning you reported was precisely

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int [3][4]' to parameter of type 'int *'
```

Another compiler I tried, gcc, said

```
expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int (*)[4]'
```

That curious notation `int (*)[4]` is just another way of saying "pointer to array of 4 `int`".

So how do we fix this?  What function `display` is trying to do is the somewhat dubious practice of "flattening" an array.  Array `a` is actually a
4×3 array, but since its three rows are going to be stored contiguously in memory, we can sort of think of it as a one-dimensional array of size 12.  That's why `display` accepts a
1-level pointer, `int *`.

So a simple (though somewhat imperfect) fix, as I mentioned in a comment, is to change the call to

```
display(&a[0][0], 3, 4);
```

Now we are passing a pointer to the array's first element's first element, which is a plain pointer-to-`int`, which is what `display` wants.  `display` wants a pointer to the first element of the "flattened" array it's going to print.

Now, you might have noticed that even when you called

```
display(a, 3, 4);
```

and got a warning, if you ignored the warning and tried running the resulting compiled program, it probably worked.  That's because of a fact which may be surprising at first.

We said that the expressions `&a`, `&a[0]`, and `&a[0][0]` all had different types.  But it turns out they all have the same value.  The address of the array is obviously the same as the address of the array's first element, and since the first element is an array, the address is also the same as the address of the array's first element's first element.  That is, if we say

```
printf("&a       = %p\n", &a);
printf("&a[0]    = %p\n", &a[0]);
printf("&a[0][0] = %p\n", &a[0][0]);
printf("a        = %p\n", a);
```

we will see exactly the same pointer value printed, four times. But, again, this does not mean that the pointers are "the same"! They have the same values, but different types.

Finally, if you're still with me, I have to explain what I meant when I said that flattening arrays is "somewhat dubious", and that my proposed fix was "imperfect".  I had also said that the array's three rows are "going to be stored contiguously in memory", and they are, *but*, there's also a rule that says that a pointer can't be used outside of the object or array it points to.  When we say &a[0][0], we get a pointer into the array's first row, but strictly speaking, we're not supposed to use that pointer outside of that first row.  But function `display` goes and uses it to step over the entire array.

As far as I know, "flattening" an array like this works, and the rulemongering which finds that it violates a constraint is more theoretical than practical, but this is what @tstanisl meant in a comment when they said in a comment that "using `display(&a[0][0],3,4);` will result in UB when accessing `q[4]`, and it's what I meant when I said that flattening arrays is "somewhat dubious".  I'm not sure there's a better fix for the compiler warning you originally complained about, since the `display` function's whole premise is slightly flawed.

Comment: I suggest adding some comment on a proper solution with VLA types