# How can a pointer to local scoped object still invoke the object method?

Tags: c++

In my understanding that might be wrong, declaring a pointer to local object is dangerous or probably has no purpose.

The following globally defined function `Factory` that returns a pointer to a local object has no purpose. Right after invoking `Factory()`, the returned address is pointing to a local object that has been destroyed.

```
Foo* Factory()
{
    // It is wrong to return the address of a local object!
    // It is only for illustration!
    Foo local{ 100 };
    return &local;
}
```

Invoking `Print()` produces a garbage value. This is understandable so far.

Now consider the second case with a local scope as follows.

```
int main()
{
    Foo* p ;
    {
        Foo local{ 100 };
        p = &local;
    }
    p->Print();// 100 is printed even though p is pointing to a local scoped object that has been destroyed.

    return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is why I can still invoke `Print()` on the pointed object that should have been destroyed. Any comments are welcome!

## Complete Example

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
private:
    int _data;
public:
    Foo(int data) :_data{ data }
    {
        std::cout << "Ctor: " << this << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Dtor: " << this << std::endl;
    }
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "Data: " << _data << std::endl;
    }
};


Foo* Factory()
{
    // It is wrong to return the address of a local object!
    // It is only for illustration!
    Foo local{ 100 };
    return &local;
}

int main_1()
{
    Foo* p = Factory();
    p->Print();// Garbage gets printed because p is pointing to a local object that has been destroyed.

    return 0;
}

int main_2()
{
    Foo* p ;
    {
        Foo local{ 100 };
        p = &local;
    }
    p->Print();// 100 is printed even though p is pointing to a local scoped object that has been destroyed.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May I ask what is with this line: `Foo(int data) : _data{data} { }`. Don't initializer lists look like `Foo(int data) : _data(data) { }`?

Comment: Both examples invoke [undefned behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). That means anything is allowed to happen from that point on, but it does not mean that either code has to necessarily crash or print garbage values.

Comment: @dxiv: If it is the answer, please submit it as your answer. I will accept it. Otherwise, I will delete my question.

Comment: @Ruan: I use uniform initializer syntax in modern c++.

Comment: Possibly dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794

Comment: @Tas: Yes only the first case is a duplicate.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Similar questions have been asked before, so I expect yours to be closed as a duplicate eventually. There is even a meta-question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235457/how-to-explain-undefined-behavior-to-know-it-all-newbies) with some entertaining answers.

Comment: @dxiv: May I ask another relevant question? Is returning an address of locally created object in heap memory such as in `Foo* Factory(){ return new Foo{ 100 };}` undefined behavior?

Comment: No. Something, which is allocated by `new` has a life-time until `delete` is called for the address returned by `new` (or end of the process). It's regardless where `new` and `delete` are placed (concerning this).

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Objects created on the heap live until deleted, so the `Factory` pattern is perfectly safe (and, in fact, fairly common).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Undefined behavior

First I want to give you a brief explanation of undefined behavior. 
If you want to you can read more here [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).


Undefinded behavior renders the entire program meaningless if certain rules of the language are violated. The compiler can basicly decide what to do. 
But like mentioned on cppreference: 
 Compilers are not required to diagnose undefined behavior (although many simple situations are diagnosed), and the compiled program is not required to do anything meaningful. So in short there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program.

## Your case

Both examples invoke undefned behavior:

```
int main_2()
{
    Foo* p ;
    {
    Foo local{ 100 };
    p = &local;
    }
    p->Print();
    return 0;
}

int main_1()
{
    Foo* p = Factory();
    p->Print();

    return 0;
}
```

So like we learned undefinded behavior is undefinded. So anything can happen. In the second case your compiler was probably smart enough to notice the issue.

#### Because the behavior is undefined your program could also crash or do other weird things.