# Which operator delete?

Tags: c++, operators

Is there a difference between:

```
operator delete(some_pointer);
```

and

```
delete some_pointer;
```

and if so what is the difference and where one should use one and where the other version of this operator?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete vs delete\[\] operators in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425728/delete-vs-delete-operators-in-c)

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913343/how-could-pairing-new-with-delete-possibly-lead-to-memory-leak-only

Comment: @0A0D: This question has nothing to do with array delete.

Comment: @UncleBens: You are right, but it has to do with delete, which the question I linked to answers (see 10 upvoted answer. It succinctly answers the question).

Comment: @0A0D, it is a related issue, but this question is not a duplicate of the one about delete vs. delete[].

Comment: @OAOD: Those questions are not duplicates (Though they are potentially parallel and provide info). They do not answer this question though.

Comment: @Dima: Questions do not have to be worded the same to be duplicates IMHO. Hence the marking.

Comment: @Martin: Did you see the 10 upvoted answer in my duplicate link? It answers it exactly.

Comment: @0A0D: Still, the reason for closing is **exact** duplicate. Unless you can find an exact duplicate, don't spoil the fun for those who just want to get reputation points :)

Comment: @UncleBens: Actually, it says exact duplicate but then it says possible duplicate in the comment and when it finally closes, it also says possible duplicate. Closing is not bad nor final. All questions can be reopened.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ironically, the `delete` operator and `operator delete()` are not the same thing.

`delete some_pointer;` calls the destructor of the object pointed to by `some_pointer`, and then calls `operator delete()` to free the memory.

You do not normally call `operator delete()` directly, because if you do, the object's destructor will not be called, and you are likely to end up with memory leaks.

The only time you have to care about `operator delete()` is when you want to do your own memory management by overriding `operator new()` and `operator delete()`.

To top it off, you should also be aware that `delete` and `delete []` are two different things.

Answer (score 6):

`operator delete()` simply frees the memory.  `delete some_pointer` calls `some_pointer`'s destructor, and then calls `operator delete()`.

Answer (score 2):

`delete some_pointer;` is the "correct" one to use.

`operator delete(some_Pointer);`  exist mainly as an artifact of the syntax for defining you own delete operator.  That is, because you define an plus operator as;

```
 myclass::operator+(myclass b) {....}
```

you really could write:

```
 myclass c = a.operator+(b);
```

but no one ever does that. They use:

```
 myclass c = a + b;
```

Similarly, you could write `operator delete(some_Pointer);`, but no one ever does.

Comment: @Dima:  At what point in my answer did I say they were the same thing??  I just said to use "Delete some_Pointer" and that you could, but no one does, use the other form.

Comment: they say that they are not in the same relationship that "operator+" and "+" is. "new" will not just call "operator new" and be happy. It does something in addition. You cannot even do `some_pointer->~T(); operator delete(some_pointer)` : It will still be different, because among other things there might be class-specific operator delete functions but the manual just calls the one in scope, and if the class has a virtual destructor, the Standard requires the "operator delete" of the dynamic type of the object to be used but a manual call cannot accomplish that at all.

Answer (score 2):

At least in my experience, it's more common to *implement* `operator new` and `operator delete` than to actually use (i.e., call) them, at least directly.

Usually, you use `operator new` and `operator delete` indirectly -- you write a `new expression`, like `A *a = new A;`. To implement this, the compiler generates code that invokes `operator new` to allocate raw memory, then invokes a `A::A` to convert that raw memory into an `A` object, much as if you'd written:

```
void *temp = operator new(sizeof A);  // allocate raw memory with operator new
A *a = new(temp) A;                   // convert raw memory to object with placement new
```

When you're done with the object, you use `delete A;`. To implement that, the compiler invokes the dtor for the object, and then frees the memory, roughly like you'd done:

```
a->~A();
operator delete(a);
```

There are also `operator [] new` and `operator [] delete`, which are used when/if you allocate/delete arrays -- but there isn't necessarily any real difference between the normal version and the array version -- they both just allocate a specified amount of raw memory (though you *might* guess that the array versions will allocate relatively large amounts of memory, and do some optimization on that basis).

In any case, if you want to optimize how memory is allocated for objects of a particular class you overload these to do it. There are a fair number of existing implementations that you can drop-in and use, especially for situations where you expect to allocate a large number of tiny objects so you need to minimize the overhead associated with each allocation (e.g., [HeapLayers](http://www.drdobbs.com/184402039), Loki's small block allocator).

One interesting little tidbit: `operator new`, `operator [] new`, `operator delete` and operator [] delete`are always`static`class members, even if you don't explicitly include`static` in their declaration/definition.

There are also global versions of all four (`::operator new`, `::operator [] new`, `::operator delete` and `::operator [] delete`). These mark the "border" between the "internal" C++ memory management, and the outside world. Typically they allocate relatively large chunks of memory from the operating system, and then return smaller pieces to the rest of the program upon request. If you want to (try to) optimize memory management for your entire program, you typically do it by overloading (or, really, replacing) these. Again, the typical reason would be if you expect to allocate a lot of small objects (but not in just a few classes). One example of this is the [Boost Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html) library.

Direct use of any of the above is generally restricted to situations where you need a block of *raw* memory, *not* objects. One example would be implementing your own container classes. For example, `std::vector` normally uses `::operator new` (via an Allocator object) to allocate memory in which to store objects. Since it needs to be able to allocate storage, but only later (or perhaps never) create objects in that storage, it can't just use something like `data = new T[size];` -- it has to allocate raw memory, then use placement new to create objects in the memory as you add them to the collection (e.g., when you `push_back` an object). The same is true with `std::deque`. If you wanted (for example) to implement your own circular buffer "from the ground up", handling all the memory management directly instead of using something like `vector` for storage, you'd probably need/want to do the same.