# Am I deleting this pointer correctly?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have the following code:

```
LPWSTR pszDSPath = NULL;
pszDSPath = new WCHAR[  wcslen(pwszFilter)+
                        wcslen(wstrServer.c_str())+
                        wcslen(var.bstrVal) +
                        1
                     ];

// ....
// ....

if(pszDSPath)
{
    delete pszDSPath; 
    pszDSPath = NULL;
}
```

Can the above code generate a memory leak? I'm not sure if I'm deleting `pszDSPath` correctly or not.

Comment: When you use `new[]` to allocate then you need to use `delete[]` to release memory

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete vs delete\[\] operators in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425728/delete-vs-delete-operators-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the correct `delete`.  There are two forms of `new`:  the scalar `new` that creates a single object (e.g. `new int`), and the array `new` that creates an array (e.g. `new int[42]`).

Likewise, there are two forms of `delete`:  `delete` and `delete[]`.  If you use `new`, you must use `delete` to destroy the object and if you use `new[]` you must use `delete[]` to destroy the object.

Since you have used `new[]` to create the object pointed to by `pszDSPath`, you must use `delete[] pszDSPath` to destroy the object.

Note, however, that this would be made much easier if you just used a `std::vector`:

```
std::size_t n = wcslen(pwszFilter)+
                wcslen(wstrServer.c_str())+
                wcslen(var.bstrVal) +
                1;

std::vector<WCHAR> v(n);

// &v[0] can be used as you are using pszDSPath in your current code.
```

In C++, you should eschew manual memory management:  it is extraordinarily difficult to get right and it takes a lot of work.  There are library facilities in the C++ Standard Library, including containers like `std::vector` and `std::map` and smart pointers like `std::auto_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr`, and `std::shared_ptr`, that manage object lifetimes for you.  You shouldn't do more work than you have to:  if you think you have to write `delete` somewhere in your code, your code is probably wrong.

This principle of using containers to manage resource lifetimes is based on a design pattern called Scope-Bound Resource Management (SBRM) or [Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712639/please-help-us-non-c-developers-understand-what-raii-is).

(`std::unique_ptr` is a part of C++0x designed to replace `std::auto_ptr`, and your compiler may not yet support it.  `std::shared_ptr` is also a part of C++0x, but it has been available for about a decade as a part of the Boost libraries (as `boost::shared_ptr`) and was included in C++ TR1.)

Comment: Thanks James for the detailed reply but one point confusing me which Jonathan Wood also mentioned in his comment that for character pointers it doesn't make any difference to delete the pointer either by using "delete pszDSPath" or "delete [] psdDSPath"

Comment: @RizWiz:  That statement in Jonathan Wood's answer is incorrect.  You have to correctly match `new[]` with `delete[]`.  If you don't, then the behavior of your program is undefined, which means that your program might crash or your data might be corrupted or things might appear to work for months and then suddenly stop working.

Comment: "Extraordinarily difficult" is a bit exaggerated, isn't it?

Comment: @Jörgen:  Not at all.  It's tedious and difficult in C to manually manage resources, but you don't have much of a choice in C.  It's 100 or 1000 times more difficult in C++, which adds non-local control flow (exceptions) and implicitly-called functions (especially constructors, destructors, and overloaded operators).  Not only is code that manually manages resources significantly more difficult to write correctly, it is also significantly difficult to verify such code as correct, reason about the code, and modify and maintain it without breaking it.

Comment: Maybe we have different views on what the word *extraordinarily* means. I agree that it is tedious, and more error prone to keep track of allocated resources "manually" than it is by using some RAII inspired mechanism, but I wouldn't call it *difficult*. Building a robot is what I would classify as  difficult.

Comment: @Jörgen:  If something is error-prone, then doing that something correctly is difficult.  If your scale of difficulty is so broad as to encompass all of human endeavor, then really, nothing discussed on this site is really all that difficult.  Writing a correct, exception-safe, non-trivial program in C++ without using automatic resource management is very difficult.  My rationale for this statement is the large number of bugs that I have found during maintenance, refactoring, and review of legacy code that didn't use automatic resource management.

Answer (score 1):

Use `delete[] pszDSPath` to avoid memory leaks when you have allocated an array beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Use `delete[]` to avoid undefined behavior.

However using `delete` in you case will [almost never cause a memory leak alone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1913343/57428) - either it will just work or you'll get something much much worse than a memory leak. Don't risk - use `delete[]`.