# Can I assume heap was not corrupted if _heapchk() returns "okay"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, undefined-behavior

In Visual C++ using `new[]` to allocate an array of objects and then `delete` (not `delete[]`) by default [triggers undefined behavior of the following kind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1913343/57428).

Calling destructors for all objects requires knowing the number of objects, so Visual C++ calls `::operator new[]()` to allocate a slightly bigger buffer, puts the number of elements into the beginning, then calls constructors and returns a pointer to the first object. When `delete` is done it only destroys the first object and then passes wrong pointer into `::operator delete()` which happens to be implemented exactly the same way as `::operator delete[]()` by default.

If the following

```
class Class {
public:
   ~Class() { Sleep( 0 );}
};

delete new Class[1];
```

is compiled in Release configuration and run under debugger the program stops with a breakpoint:

```
ntdll.dll!_DbgBreakPoint@0()    
ntdll.dll!_RtlpBreakPointHeap@4()  + 0x28 bytes 
ntdll.dll!_RtlpValidateHeapEntry@12()  + 0x113 bytes    
ntdll.dll!_RtlDebugFreeHeap@12()  + 0x97 bytes  
ntdll.dll!_RtlFreeHeapSlowly@12()  + 0x246cf bytes  
ntdll.dll!_RtlFreeHeap@12()  + 0x17646 bytes    
sample.exe!free(void * pBlock=0x0003339c)  Line 110 C
sample.exe!main()  Line 48  C++
sample.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 266 + 0x12 bytes   C
kernel32.dll!_BaseProcessStart@4()  + 0x23 bytes
```

which looks like a heap corruption - at least that's what I would expect in this case.

I tried to call [`_heapchk()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/2xse74he(v=vs.80).aspx) before and after that line and surprisingly it returns `_HEAPOK` both times. I also [enabled memory leak detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3(v=vs.80).aspx) and no leak is reported when program ends.

Can I assume heap is fully intact if `_heapchk()` returns `_HEAPOK`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xse74he.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The `_heapchk` function helps debug heap-related problems by checking for **minimal consistency of the heap**.

It does not check for absolute consistency and correctness:  it should be able to detect major, egregious errors, but it isn't going to catch every error.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for sure, but I've played a bit with this, and have noticed two things:

1. On release builds, the compiler sometimes puts an assembly call to "operator delete[]" even when the C++ code uses regular delete.
2. On release builds, when using the wrong delete, the CRT identifies the mismatch, and reports it via RtlpLogHeapFailure (god knows what that means...).

I'm just speculating here, but my guess is that the part of the delete that handles the heap is smarter than you think. It actually has a way to recognize what you're sending it, and treat it accordingly. So on Debug build you'll get an assertion from the additional debug tests, but on the lower level, the heap can still protect itself, and perform the right action, without getting corrupted. So if that's really the case, on VC++ the type of delete merely affects the destructions, and the heap part is done right either way. Other compilers might behave differently.

And that's why _heapchk() won't return a failure...

Answer (score 1):

No, _heapchk returning _HEAPOK simply means it could not find a problem or that the heap doesn't support validation.

I'd say it's more likely that you're delete'ing an uninitialized pointer when you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

You mean that you call a function after invoking undefined behavior, and still want to trust the result?  ;-)

Here I just guess that the undefined behavior can manifest itself in a lot of ways, the most common being "seems to work". Surprised?

Other unusual circumstances are:
- you call new and delete in the same statement.
- you only allocate a single element.
- you only do it in one place in the entire program.
- the destructor doesn't do anything significant to memory allocation.
All of these can affect the way the optimizer produces the code, and as eran said  - the compiler can easily see all this and realize what you are doing. It is not stupid!