# Is it "safe" on Linux to mix `new[]` and `delete`?

Tags: c++, linux

Someone on IRC claimed that, although allocating with `new[]` and deleting with `delete` (*not* `delete[]`) is UB, on Linux platforms (no further details about the OS) it would be safe.

Is this true? Is it guaranteed? Is it to do with something in POSIX that specifies that dynamically-allocated blocks should not have metadata at the start?

Or is it just completely untrue?

---

**Yes, I know I shouldn't do it. I never would.
I am curious about the veracity of this idea; *that's it*!**

---

By "safe", I mean: "will not cause behaviour other than were the original allocation performed by `new`, or were the de-allocation performed by `delete[]`". This means that we might see `1` "element" destruction *or* `n`, but no crashing.

Comment: I doubt this is ever safe for types with a non-trivial destructor, and even if it is that would depend more on the compiler than the OS, I think.

Comment: I don't think POSIX deals with C++ at all.

Comment: What does `safe` mean to you? Safe as in: "the memory was freed" or safe as in: "**all** the destructors were executed".

Comment: @MatthieuM.: The former, as if `new` had been used instead (I guess), with none of the typical symptoms of UB code

Comment: If there is such situation, when it is safe, it's fully dependant on `malloc()` and `free()` implementation - OS has nothing to do with userspace heap.

Comment: How `new[]` and `delete` expressions are implemented depends on the compiler/std lib, not on the OS. I don't know how GCC deals with it, but I _very_ seriously doubt `delete new std::string[10]` would call ten dtors.

Comment: @Griwes: This really doesn't depend on `malloc` in any way. `free` never calls C++ destructors.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus, well, kinda right, but it depends on definition of "safe", again.

Comment: Any definition of "safe" which excludes "respects invariants and postconditions set by the core language" isn't worth having.

Comment: FWIW, here's how safe it looks on ideone, even with a single destructor to call: http://ideone.com/ZlPDM. I get the same behaviour on my Linux box.

Comment: [This article might be of interest](http://web.archive.org/web/20080703153358/http://taossa.com/index.php/2007/01/03/attacking-delete-and-delete-in-c)

Comment: @Jesse: Ah, absolutely! Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is delete\[\] equal to delete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553382/is-delete-equal-to-delete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely not safe as you can simply try out with the following code:

```
#include<iostream>

class test {
public:
  test(){ std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl; }
  ~test(){ std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  test * t = new test[ 10 ];
  delete t;
  return 1;
}
```

Have a look at http://ideone.com/b8BiQ . It fails misserably.

It may work when you do not use classes, but only fundamental types, but even that is not guaranteed.

**EDIT**: Some explanations for those of you who want to know *why* this crashes:

`new` and `delete` mainly serve as wrappers around `malloc()`, hence calling `free()` on a newed pointer is most of the time "safe" (remember to call the destructor), but you should not rely on it. For `new[]` and `delete[]` however the situation is more complicated.

When an array of classes gets constructed using `new[]` each default constructor will be called in turn. When you do `delete[]` each destructor gets called. However each destructor also has to be supplied a `this` pointer to use inside as a hidden parameter. So before calling the destructor the program has to find the locations of all objects within the reserved memory, to pass these locations as `this` pointers to the destructor. So all information that is later needed to reconstruct this information needs to be stored somewhere.

Now the easiest way would be to have a global map somewhere around, which stores this information for all `new[]`ed pointers. In this case if you `delete` is called instead of `delete[]` only one of the destructors would be called and the entry would not be removed from a map. However this method is usually not used, because maps are slow and memory management should be as fast as possible.

Hence for the stdlibc++ a different solution is used. Since only a few bytes are needed as additional information, it is the fastest to just over-allocate by these few bytes, store the information at the beginning of the memory and return the pointer to the memory after the bookkeeping. So if you allocate an array of 10 objects of 10 bytes each, the programm will allocate `100+X` bytes where `X` is the size of the data which is needed to reconstruct the this.

So in this case it looks something like this

```
| Bookkeeping | First Object | Second Object |....
^             ^
|             This is what is returned by new[]
|
this is what is returned by malloc()
```

So in case you pass the pointer you have recieved from `new[]` to `delete[]` it will call all destructors, then substract `X` from the pointer and give that one to `free()`. However if you call `delete` instead, it will call a destructor for the first object and then immediately pass that pointer to `free()`, which means `free()` has just been passed a pointer which was never malloced, which means the result is UB.

Have a look at http://ideone.com/tIiMw , to see what gets passed to `delete` and `delete[]`. As you can see, the pointer returned from `new[]` is not the pointer which was allocated inside, but 4 is added to it before it is being returned to `main()`. When calling `delete[]` correctly the same four is substracted an we get the correct pointer within `delete[]` however this substraction is missing when calling `delete` and we get the wrong pointer.

In case of calling `new[]` on a fundamental type, the compiler immediately knows that it will not have to call any destructors later and it just optimizes the bookkeeping away. However it is definitely allowed to write bookkeeping even for fundamental types. And it is also allowed to add bookkeeping in case you call `new`.

This bookkeeping in front of the real pointer is actually a very good trick, in case you ever need to write your own memory allocation routines as a replacement of `new` and `delete`. There is hardly any limit on what you can store there , so one should never assume that anything returned from `new` or `new[]` was actually returned from `malloc()`.

Comment: That's not a proof of "safeness". Admittedly I didn't give a strict definition of "safe".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I never said it was a proof of safeness... It isn't. It's a proof of unsafenes. In this case not all constructors get called and a horrible glibc memory corruption error is produced (at least at ideone and my machine). This means it is unsafe.

Comment: Er, I meant "unsafeness". And, sorry, I missed the SIGABRT completely. I take back my comment (though I still don't care how many destructors calls are made).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: why not? So you're saying that it doesn't have to *work* in order to be "safe"?

Comment: @jalf: Essentially. This question's definition of safe -- though admittedly unclear -- was "will not cause behaviour other than were the original allocation a `new` _or_ the de-allocation a `delete[]`".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: and the correct number of destructor calls is part of that behavior. Mixing them will change the number of destructor calls, even if everything else works. So by your definition, changing the number of destructor calls means it is not safe

Comment: @jalf: Nah, not so. Changing the number of destructor calls is covered by my "_or_".

Comment: I don't see how. If you use `new[N]` with `delete`, then N constructors and 1 destructor will be called. You say that if the behavior matches *one* of these two cases, it is "safe: (a)`new`/`delete` or (b)`new[N]`/`delete[]`. Case (a) will call 1 ctor and 1 dtor, so it is different. Case (b) will call N ctors and N dtors, so it is different. If the behavior does not match *either* of the behaviors you consider safe, then it must be unsafe

Comment: @jalf: Please use `@replies`! changing the number of destructor calls leads is involved in (b), which is valid as we all know.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: that made precisely no sense to me.

Comment: So you're unable to explain what you meant? "the number of destructor calls leads is involved" isn't a meaningful sentence in English.

Answer (score 13):

Of course it's not true. That person is mixing up several different concerns:

- how does the OS handle allocations/deallocations
- correct calls to constructors and destructors
- UB means UB

On the first point, I'm sure he's correct. It is common to handle both in the same way on that level: it is simply a request for X bytes, or a request to release the allocation starting at address X. It doesn't really matter if it's an array or not.

On the second point, everything falls apart. `new[]` calls the constructor for *each* element in the allocated array. `delete` calls the destructor for the one element at the specified address. And so, if you allocate an array of objects, and free it with `delete`, only one element will have its destructor invoked. (This is easy to forget because people invariably test this with arrays of `int`s, in which case this difference is unnoticeable)

And then there's the third point, the catch-all. It's UB, and that means it's UB. The compiler may make optimizations based on the assumption that your code does not exhibit any undefined behavior. If it does, it may break some of these assumptions, and seemingly unrelated code might break.

Comment: Yes, your reasoning on the third point is easy to forget, but definitive.

Answer (score 7):

Even if it happens to be safe on *some* environment, don't do it. **There's no reason to want to do it.**

Even if it did return the right memory to the OS, the destructors wouldn't be called properly.

It's definitely not true for all or even most Linuxes, your IRC friend is talking bollocks.

POSIX has *nothing* to do with C++. In general, this is unsafe. If it works anywhere, it's because of the compiler and library, not the OS.

Comment: Ok, on *my* Linux distro (Kubuntu), it definitely is not safe.

Comment: I guess it fully depends on `malloc()` detailed implementation; so, probably, it have nothing to do with OS, but depends on stdlib implementation. Then, using specific library impl., it could be safe on every OS. But don't do it. It's silly and doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Best example is using `delete` instead of `delete[]` and leaking memory (or other resources) because of dtors not being run. I doubt that any implementation will "fix" that.

Comment: @Griwes: `malloc()`  is not the guilty party. In both cases of `new` and `new[]` it just provides some bare memory. However in one case the operator also has to store information about how many destructors to call and where to find these objectes on which to call them.

Comment: @LiKao, trueness of your sentence depends on definition of "safe".

Comment: @Griwes: I wasn't talking about safety in my sentence. I was correcting your sentence. There is nothing in my sentence which depends on any definition of safety at all.

Comment: @LiKao, but the OP was talking about safety. And I was talking about "is not the guilty party".

Comment: @Griwes: Sure, I got that. But `malloc()` or the cstdlib isn't in any way responsible for anything having to do with the difference between `new[]` or `new` and `delete[]` or `delete`. There is some more magic after the call to malloc involved, ussually by adding some additional information at the beginning of the block and then returning an offseted pointer. The correct offset has to substracted again before calling `free` from within `delete` or `delete[]`. This offset is calculated differently within `delete` and `delete[]`. Hence in one case `free()` just get's passed an invalid pointer.

Comment: @Griwes: Ok, just looked up the standard for `free()`. Funny enough I always thought it had to crash when the pointer passed to is was not malloced (or previously freed). Seems like this is "only" UB, so there may be implementations which just discard such "invalid" pointers. I guess then it depends both on the implementation of `malloc()`/`free()` as well as `new[]`/`delete[]`.

Answer (score 3):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1913343/57428) discusses in great details when exactly  mixing `new[]` and `delete` *looks safe* (no observable problems) on Visual C++. I suppose that by "on Linux" you actually mean "with gcc" and I've observed very similar results with gcc on ideone.com.

Please note that this ***requires***:

1. global `operator new()` and `operator new[]()` functions to be implemented identically and
2. the compiler optimizing away the "prepend with number of elements" allocation overhead

and also only works for types with trivial destructors.

Even with these requirements met there's no guarantee it will work on a specific version of a specific compiler. You'll be much better off simply not doing that - relying on undefined behavior is a very bad idea.

Comment: I have no idea what the person meant by "on Linux" further than what was said. Good link, ta

Answer (score 0):

I expect that `new[]` and `delete[]` just boil down to `malloc()` and `free()` under Linux (gcc, glibc, libstdc++), except that the con(de)structors get called.  The same for `new` and `delete` except that the con(de)structors get called differently.  This means that if his constructors and destructors don't matter, then he can probably get away with it.  But why try?

Comment: `new`, `delete`, `new[]` and `delete[]` may use extra accounting information. It is only guaranteed that the info generated by `new` must be understood by `delete` and the info generated by `new[]` must be understood by `delete[]`. Hence this might cause havok in other cases as well.

Comment: Absolutely true.  I am not talking about what is guaranteed, I am just talking about what is probably true for now.  So yep, nobody should try this kind of trick.

Comment: No it is not "probably true" that they just boil down to `malloc()` and `free()`. As you can see from the example I gave in the answer above there is much more going on besides the bare call to `malloc()` and `free()` and this extra logic usually leads to a heap corruption under Linux which is fatal for the program. The usual fastest trick to take care of the accounting info is to store it directly with the allocated block which is fatal when the wrong operator is called on it later.