# How to free low heap memory in a function？

Tags: c++, heap-memory

```
 bool containsDuplicate(vector<int>& nums) {
    int n=nums.size();
    int* counter=new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;++i){
        ++counter[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        if(int i>1) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see,I applied for a heap space'counter';
So,I want know if I need to free the heap memory,how to free the heap memory? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [deleting c++ array from heap and memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111302/deleting-c-array-from-heap-and-memory-leak)

Comment: `if(int i>1)` that does not look like valid C++. If your compiler ate this without complaints, throw it out and get a better one.

Comment: `++counter[i];` is not going to behave as `counter` has not been initialised.  Please red [ask] with a [mcve];  the code should compile unless you are asking about compilation errors.  Why mix `std::vector` and c-arrays? and yes you need to `delete [] counter;`

Comment: why not use a `std::vector<int> counter;` ?

Comment: You are already using `vector` in your program, but you didn't use it where it could have been used:  `std::vector<int> counter (n);`.  Then all the issues are solved.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken thie function will always return `false` if you initialize `counter` to contain 0's. For some reason it also ignore the last element of `counter`.

Comment: Also, this code would fail to find a duplicate for something simple as `{1, 10 ,1}`, even if you fixed all the issues, unless you are assuming that `nums` contains only integers from `0` to `n-1`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well, the function would also fail for `{0, 1, 1}`, because it doesn't actually read `nums`, except in `int n=nums.size();`.

Answer (score 1):

First the direct answers to your questions, but read on after that:

> I want know if I need to free the heap memory

Yes, you should.

> how to free the heap memory?

```
delete [] counter;
```

Note that the `[]` is essential as `counter` is a dynamic array. For non-array memory allocated with `new`, the `[]` should be omitted (see [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete)).

### Issues in your code

1. `if(int i>1)` is not valid C++ syntax. It should just be `if(i>1)`
2. `counter` is not initialised, so the outcome is not reliable.
3. The first loop does not count occurrences of *values* but of *indices*, so (when the previous issues are fixed) the returned value will always be `false`.
4. If all of the above is fixed, this function can only deal with values that are in the range {0, n-1}, as other values are not valid indices of the `counter` array. Use a `set` instead. This also makes the question on memory management irrelevant, as the set will be destroyed when the function exits.

### Proposed solution

Once the decision is taken to use a set, things become a lot easier. The set constructor can be given a range (of the `nums` vector) and once that set is contructed, it suffices to compare its size with that of the vector:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

bool containsDuplicate(vector<int>& nums) {
    set<int> uniques(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    return uniques.size() < nums.size();
}
```

Comment: You could emphasize the `[]` part which is important to use for dynamic arrays and to not use for single objects.

Comment: Added a phrase about that.