# C++ Allocate Memory Without Activating Constructors

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm reading in values from a file which I will store in memory as I read them in. I've read on here that the correct way to handle memory location in C++ is to always use new/delete, but if I do:

```
DataType* foo = new DataType[sizeof(DataType) * numDataTypes];
```

Then that's going to call the default constructor for each instance created, and I don't want that. I was going to do this:

```
DataType* foo;
char* tempBuffer=new char[sizeof(DataType) * numDataTypes];
foo=(DataType*) tempBuffer;
```

But I figured that would be something poo-poo'd for some kind of type-unsafeness. So what should I do?

And in researching for this question now I've seen that some people are saying arrays are bad and vectors are good. I was trying to use arrays more because I thought I was being a bad boy by filling my programs with (what I thought were) slower vectors. What should I be using???

Comment: Come on, you are worrying about efficiency while your first line of code is incorrect!

Comment: If you don't have a performance problem you should choose the solution that is easiest and safest to work with

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use vectors!!! Since you know the number of elements, make sure that you reserve the memory first (by calling myVector.reserve(numObjects) before you then insert the elements.).

By doing this, you will not call the default constructors of your class.

So use

```
std::vector<DataType> myVector; // does not reserve anything
...
myVector.reserve(numObjects); // tells vector to reserve memory
```

Comment: Vectors are usually a good option, but they still don't let you call a constructor of your choice.  Vector elements are always copy-constructed.

Comment: True! You can then use a vector of smart pointers to your objects if you would like (and hence the copy constructor of the smart pointer will be called instead).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: in C++0x, wouldn't `emplace_back` allow you to use the constructor of your choice ?

Comment: @Matthieu: Correct, C++0x will finally fill in this missing piece (I use the future tense because I think this capability isn't implemented in any compilers yet).

Answer (score 8):

You can use `::operator new` to allocate an arbitrarily sized hunk of memory.

```
DataType* foo = static_cast<DataType*>(::operator new(sizeof(DataType) * numDataTypes));
```

The main advantage of using `::operator new` over `malloc` here is that it throws on failure and will integrate with any new_handlers etc. You'll need to clean up the memory with `::operator delete`

```
::operator delete(foo);
```

Regular `new Something` will of course invoke the constructor, that's the point of `new` after all.

It is one thing to avoid *extra* constructions (e.g. default constructor) or to defer them for performance reasons, it is another to skip any constructor altogether. I get the impression you have code like

```
DataType dt;
read(fd, &dt, sizeof(dt));
```

If you're doing that, you're already throwing type safety out the window anyway.

Why are you trying to accomplish by not invoking the constructor?

Comment: What's the advantage of calling `::operator new` directly vs `new char[]` like the question already mentions?

Comment: @Ben Voigt, communicating intent mostly in this case. You're not trying to create an array of `char's, you're allocating some memory. The second issue is IIRC array new will initialize PODs to 0, which carries some slight overhead.

Comment: Seems to be default-initialized which, since `char` is not a class type, does nothing.  Unfortunately I have only the C++0x draft standard in front of me and this is definitely one of the things being changed (in C++0x braced-initializers are allowed on array new).

Answer (score 2):

You can allocate memory with `new char[]`, call the constructor you want for each element in the array, and then everything will be type-safe.  Read [What are uses of the C++ construct "placement new"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362953/what-are-uses-of-the-c-construct-placement-new)

That's how `std::vector` works underneath, since it allocates a little extra memory for efficiency, but doesn't construct any objects in the extra memory until they're actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a vector. It will allow you to construct its contents one-by-one (via `push_back` or the like), which sounds like what you're wanting to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<DataType> dataTypeVec(numDataTypes);
```

And as you've been told, your first line there contains a bug (no need to multiply by sizeof).

Comment: You might want to test that before you claim that the default constructor isn't called.  (It is, once, and then the copy constructor is called `numDataTypes` times.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't care about efficiency using vector if you will not insert new elements anywhere but at the end of the vector (since elements of vector are stored in a contiguous memory block).

Answer (score 1):

Building on what others have said, if you ran this program while piping in a text file of integers that would fill the data field of the below class, like:

```
./allocate < ints.txt
```

Then you can do:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyDataType {
public:
  int dataField;
};


int main() {

  const int TO_RESERVE = 10;

  vector<MyDataType> everything;
  everything.reserve( TO_RESERVE );

  MyDataType temp;
  while( cin >> temp.dataField ) {
    everything.push_back( temp );
  }

  for( unsigned i = 0; i < everything.size(); i++ ) {
    cout << everything[i].dataField;
    if( i < everything.size() - 1 ) {
      cout << ", ";
    }
  }
}
```

Which, for me with a list of 4 integers, gives:

```
5, 6, 2, 6
```