# Initializing an array of trivially_copyable but not default_constructible objects from bytes. Confusion in [intro.object]

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing

We are initializing (large) arrays of `trivially_copiable` objects from secondary storage, and questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40873520/1027706) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40930475/1027706) leaves us with little confidence in our implemented approach.

Below is a minimal example to try to illustrate the "worrying" parts in the code.
Please also [find it on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bdezbseGq).

### Example

Let's have a `trivially_copyable` but not `default_constructible` user type:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(double a, double b) :
        alpha{a}, 
        beta{b}
    {}

    double alpha;
    double beta;
};
```

Trusting [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable):

> Objects of trivially-copyable types that are not potentially-overlapping subobjects are the only C++ objects that may be safely copied with std::memcpy or serialized to/from binary files with std::ofstream::write()/std::ifstream::read().

Now, we want to read a binary file into an dynamic array of `Foo`. Since `Foo` is not default constructible, we cannot simply:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo[]> invalid{new Foo[dynamicSize]}; // Error, no default ctor
```

#### Alternative (A)

Using uninitialized `unsigned char` array as storage.

```
std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> storage{
    new unsigned char[dynamicSize * sizeof(Foo)] };

input.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(storage.get()), dynamicSize * sizeof(Foo));

std::cout << reinterpret_cast<Foo *>(storage.get())[index].alpha << "\n";
```

Is there an UB because object of actual type `Foo` are never explicitly created in `storage`?

#### Alternative (B)

The storage is explicitly typed as an array of `Foo`.

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo[]> storage{
    static_cast<Foo *>(::operator new[](dynamicSize * sizeof(Foo))) };

input.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(storage.get()), dynamicSize * sizeof(Foo));

std::cout << storage[index].alpha << "\n";
```

This alternative was inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576380/1027706). Yet, is it better defined? It seems there are still no explicit creation of object of type `Foo`.

It is notably getting rid of the `reinterpret_cast` when accessing the `Foo` data member (this cast might have violated the [Type Aliasing rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing)).

### Overall Questions

- Are any of these alternatives defined by the standard? Are they actually different?

  - If not, is there a correct way to implement this (without first initializing all Foo instances to values that will be discarded immediately after)
- Is there any difference in undefined behaviours between versions of the C++ standard?
  (In particular, please see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873520/reinterpret-cast-creating-a-trivially-default-constructible-object#comment109589840_40874245) with regard to C++20)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're trying to do ultimately is create an array of some type `T` by `memcpy`ing bytes from elsewhere without default constructing the `T`s in the array first.

Pre-C++20 cannot do this without provoking UB at some point.

The problem ultimately comes down to [[intro.object]/1, which defines the ways objects get created](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#1):

> An object is created by a definition, by a new-expression, when implicitly changing the active member of a union, or when a temporary object is created ([conv.rval], [class.temporary]).

If you have a pointer of type `T*`, but no `T` object has been created in that address, you can't just pretend that the pointer points to an actual `T`. You have to cause that `T` to come into being, and that requires doing one of the above operations. And the only available one for your purposes is the new-expression, which requires that the `T` is default constructible.

If you want to `memcpy` into such objects, they must exist *first*. So you have to create them. And for arrays of such objects, that means they need to be default constructible.

So if it is at all possible, you need a (likely defaulted) default constructor.

---

In C++20, certain operations can implicitly create objects (provoking "implicit object creation" or IOC). IOC only works on implicit lifetime types, which [for classes](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.prop#9):

> A class S is an implicit-lifetime class if it is an aggregate or has at least one trivial eligible constructor and a trivial, non-deleted destructor.

Your class qualifies, as it has a trivial copy constructor (which is "[eligible](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/special#6)") and a trivial destructor.

If you create an array of byte-wise types (`unsigned char`, `std::byte`, or `char`), [this is said to "implicitly create objects" in that storage](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#13). This property also applies to the memory returned by `malloc` and `operator new`. This means that if you do certain kinds of undefined behavior to pointers to that storage, the system will automatically create objects (at the point where the array was created) that would make that behavior well-defined.

So if you allocate such storage, cast a pointer to it to a `T*`, and then start using it as though it pointed to a `T`, the system will automatically create `T`s in that storage, so long as it was appropriately aligned.

Therefore, your alternative A works just fine:

When you apply `[index]` to your casted pointer, C++ will *retroactively* create an array of `Foo` in that storage. That is, because you used the memory like an array of `Foo` exists there, C++20 will *make* an array of `Foo` exist there, exactly as if you had created it back at the `new unsigned char` statement.

However, alternative B will not work as is. You did not use `new[] Foo` to create the array, so you cannot use `delete[] Foo` to delete it. You *can* still use `unique_ptr`, but you'll have to create a deleter that explicitly calls `operator delete` on the pointer:

```
struct mem_delete
{
  template<typename T>
  void operator(T *ptr)
  {
    ::operator delete[](ptr);
  }
};

std::unique_ptr<Foo[], mem_delete> storage{
    static_cast<Foo *>(::operator new[](dynamicSize * sizeof(Foo))) };

input.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(storage.get()), dynamicSize * sizeof(Foo));

std::cout << storage[index].alpha << "\n";
```

Again, `storage[index]` creates an array of `T` as if it were created at the time the memory was allocated.

Comment: What if I have two pointers of different implicit lifetime types, say `T*` and `U*`, to the same storage returned by `malloc`, are they both having active objects of `T` and `U` within the same storage at the same time or violating the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: @VainMan: It is the use of the pointer that causes the UB, and therefore that causes IOC to retroactively happen. Because IOC only happens in one place (the place that allocated the memory to begin with), it only happens once. So if no *single object* creation can satisfy both uses, you get UB. Note that if `T` was standard layout and its first member was `U`, then they both have the same address, so IOC can create a `T` and that would be enough to satisfy both use cases.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can't use `delete` to free memory allocated with `new []`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete

Answer (score 0):

My first question is:  What are you trying to achieve?

- Is there an issue with reading each entry individually?
- Are you assuming that your code will speed up by reading an array?
- Is latency really a factor?
- Why can't you just add a default constructor to the class?
- Why can't you enhance `input.read()` to read directly into an array? See `std::extent_v<T>`

Assuming the constraints you defined, I would start with writing it the simple way, reading one entry at a time, and benchmark it.
Having said that, that which you describe is a common paradigm and, yes, can break a lot of rules.

C++ is very (overly) cautious about things like alignment which can be issues on certain platforms and non-issues on others.  This is only "undefined behaviour" because no cross-platform guarantees can be given by the C++ standard itself, even though many techniques work perfectly well in practice.

The textbook way to do this is to create an empty buffer and memcpy into a proper object, but as your input is serialised (potentially by another system), there isn't actually a guarantee that the padding and alignment will match the memory layout which the local compiler determined for the sequence so you would still have to do this one item at a time.

My advice is to write a unit-test to ensure that there are no issues and potentially embed that into the code as a static assertion.  The technique you described breaks some C++ rules but that doesn't mean it's breaking, for example, x86 rules.

Comment: By definition, you cannot unit-test an undefined behaviour. (e.g. passing all unit-tests ever written but failling only once at the most critical time in production is a very valid undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative (A): Accessing a —non-static— member of an object before its lifetime begins.
The behavior of the program is undefined (See: [[basic.life]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6.2)).

Alternative (B): Implicit call to the implicitly deleted default constructor.
The program is ill-formed (See: [[class.default.ctor]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#class.default.ctor-5)).

I'm not sure about the latter. If someone more knowledgeable knows if/why this is UB please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the memory yourself, and then return a `unique_ptr` which uses a custom deleter. Since you can't use `new[]`, you can't use the plain version of `unique_ptr<T[]>` and you need to manually call the destructor and deleter using an allocator.

```
template <class Allocator = std::allocator<Foo>>
struct FooDeleter : private Allocator {
  using pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer;

  explicit FooDeleter(const Allocator &alloc, len) : Allocator(alloc), len(len) {}

  void operator()(pointer p) {
    for (pointer i = p; i != p + len; ++i) {
      Allocator::destruct(i);
    }
    Allocator::deallocate(p, len);
  }

  size_t len;
};

std::unique_ptr<Foo[], FooDeleter<>> create(size_t len) {
   std::allocator<Foo> alloc;
   Foo *p = nullptr, *i = nullptr;
   try {
     p = alloc.allocate(len);
     for (i = p; i != p + len; ++i) {
       alloc.construct(i , 1.0f, 2.0f);
     }
   } catch (...) {
     while (i > p) {
       alloc.destruct(i--);
     }
     if (p)
       alloc.deallocate(p);
     throw;
   }
   return std::unique_ptr<Foo[], FooDeleter<>>{p, FooDeleter<>(alloc, len)};
}
```

Comment: If I understand your proposal, it is still constructing each `Foo` individually with dummy values in `create()`. The question intention is to avoid that.

Comment: This is a basic example to use allocators with unique_ptr. You can simply replace the construction with a copy, be it a  `read`, `memcpy` or simply calling `std::uninitialized_copy(std::istream_iterator<Foo>(std::in)), std::istream_iterator<Foo>(), p);`.